# Wiki.js GitHub integration failure

Tags: wiki.js

I was asked to set up Wiki.js for my company, and I picked GitHub authentication, which seemed pretty easy, but it doesn't work.  It's clearly trying, but it comes to a message that says *Invalid Authentication Provider*.

I tried from a different browser and it successfully bounced me over to GitHub to get authenticated, and I did, but then it bounced over to the same message.

So I know that the basics of it are configured correctly, and GitHub is doing it's part of the auth successfully.  But there's something still not right.

There's only four points of configuration.  A homepage URL, and a callback URL, which result in a Client ID and a Client Secret.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've followed [these instructions](https://docs.requarks.io/auth/github) and everything works as expected...